# Cisco Prime: Accurate Wi-Fi association history?

Tags: cisco, wireless

I'm running Prime 3.7 with a 2504 WLC (8.5.151.0) and am finding that the client association history under Monitor -> Clients and Users -> [select a client] does not show associations that last less than 5 minutes.

I would like to be able to see *all* associations in a given client's history; does anyone know a way to do this? Is there some other part of Prime I need to be looking in? Or is there a setting in Prime or the WLC that filters out brief associations that I need to change? Any other ideas?

Comment: I found half an answer to this. It turns out that Prime collects the association data shown in "association history" by polling the WLCs, every 5 minutes by default. The minimum poll interval is 1 minute which is still too long to get an accurate log.

If I have to, I could have the WLCs send SNMP traps upon association to an external server and write something to parse them, but if there is an easier / Cisco-provided way to access this data, I would love to hear it.